# C# read file line into List and use as parameters

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader, ilist

I'm not quite sure how to do this, but I am trying to read a .CSV file line-by-line storing each independent line into a List<>. Then loop through the list and use each item (row) as a signature for a new instance of my Employee class.

**database.csv**

```
John Doe,4568,0
Jane Smith,6154,1   // this represents my constructors signature
...
...
```

**Employee.cs** (constructor only)

```
public Employee(string emp, string id, int state)
    {
        EmpName = emp;
        IdName = id;
        _empState = state;
    }
```

**my method in a Repository class:**

```
public IList<Employee> getListOfActiveEmployees()
    {

        string filePath = @"(filepath)\database.csv";

        var emp = new List<Employee>();

        //var LogFile = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

        List<string> Lines = new List<string>();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                Lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        foreach (var row in Lines)
        {
            emp += new Employee(row);
        }

        return emp;
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required 
formal parameter 'id' of 'Employee.Employee(string, string, int)'
```

My guess is that it's reading the whole line as my first input? Is there a way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the string so you can distribute it on the parameters of the constructor.

```
while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine(); // store the value in a variable
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) // check if not empty
    {
        string[] val = line.Split(','); // assuming it returns three values

        // you can add extra validation here
        // array should have 3 values
        // otherwise it will throw invalid index exception
        emp.Add(new Employee(val[0], val[1], Convert.ToInt32(val[2])));
    }
}

return emp;
```

Comment: Awesome, and that does away with the other for-loop. It makes sense now, each line is being read as a string so of course it would be passed into the first parameter. Thank you John, I'll read up on the Split() function.

Answer (score 1):

When you construct an employee, you are using a constructor that you have not implemented. Employee takes a string, string and an int. Parse the line into the three expected parameters:

```
foreach (var row in Lines)
{
    var params = row.Split(',');
    emp.Add(new Employee(params[0], params[1], Convert.ToInt32(params[2])));
}
```